# How to display one item in LazyRow in JetPack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Like Viewpager or in RecyclerView we can achive this behavior of swiping only one item per swipe. In RecyclerView we achiveve this behavior by using SnapHelper. Any idea how to achieve this behavior in Compose?

Comment: I don't understand what're you trying to achieve, please update your question so it doesn't require `RecyclerView` knowledge to answer

Comment: I am trying to achieve the behavior of Viewpager. In viewpager we swipe to left or right, and it results into swiping only one item per swipe. But in LazyRow in Compose, if we swipe to left or right, we can swipe multiple items. Since LazyRow mimics the RecyclerView (in non compose fashion) and to achieve this behavior of Viewpager in recyclerview we use SnapHelper otherwise recyclerview also scrolls multiple items per swipe (horizontal). I don't want to user viewpager and achieve this thing in LazyRow or in any other way.

Comment: You need [Accompanist Pager](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/)

Comment: Looks like the right option. I guess with it I will be able to create a horizontal list, with one main item visible and the other partially available. And swiping one time will only swipe one item. Thank you